# Running/Debugging Pycharm Python Scripts with remote Docker Machine

Tags: python, docker-compose, pycharm, docker-machine

I'm using a remote workstation (Ubunutu 18.04) with a GPU via Docker Machine. With PyCharm Professional 2018.1.4 I can connect remotely to the workstation and create/start containers, connect to them and attach a terminal.

The problem occurs when I try to run a python script via docker compose with PyCharm. I get the error:

> python: can't open file '/opt/project/testing.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  densepose:
    build: Dockerfile
    image: densepose
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/project # I have tried adding and removing this to no avail
      - ./included_files:/included_files
      - ./output:/output
```

And I am using the Dockerfile from [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DensePose/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile)

I have tried using both Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 with PyCharm to connect to the remote station to do this but I receive the same error.

**Edit:** 
After more digging it seems to be related to PyCharm copying files pr-emptively to the remote docker-machine. It should be using docker-machine scp but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: so will the OP be able to award himself the bounty? ;)

Comment: Solved it 5 minutes after putting on the bounty... Classic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paths mappings don't deploy your files to the remote server. You need to create a remote server configuration and upload your files to the remote machine.

Pycharm has a tool for deployment as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html)